# PLSQL Execute Immediate with Dynamic Using

Tags: dynamic, plsql, using, execute-immediate

I am dynamically building a search query with bind variables with at least 1 and at most 7 different potential criteria.  I know I can do this -

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql USING bind_var1, bind_var2 or
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql USING bind_var3, bind_var5, bind_var7.
```

Is it possible to include the bind variables within the sql?

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :bind_var1 AND name = :bind_var2 USING bind_var1, bind_var2'
```

and do

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql?
```

I want and need to dynamically build the USING piece instead of writing a lot of IF THEN statements.

Answer (score 0):

your **USING bind_var1, bind_var2** pice of code should be out side os your sql string and come at the end of **execute immediate** statement and also for select senarios try to use dynamic sql for select with a cursor unless you want to select into a variable

Answer (score 0):

According to your tags, I assume this will be used inside some kind of PL/SQL block. So, maybe are you looking for the [`open for`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/openfor_statement.htm) statement.

This allows you to get a *cursor* on an dynamic query:

```
sql := 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :bind_var1 AND name = :bind_var2';
open my_cursor for sql using bind_var1, bind_var2';

-- do whatever you need with your cursor
```